# Get Count of Measure for Aggregate Bins in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have below data :

[image]

I have created 2 measures in dax for Product Count and Amount Total.

Product Count=DistinctCount(table[Product])

Amount Total=sum(table[Amount])

[image]

I want to show output as below:

[image]

For that I have created 2 measures Product density band and Amount band using switch case.
But I am not able get the count of ids for each band.
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

We need two configuration tables

The `Amount Band` table

[image]

And the Product `Density Band` table

[image: Product Density Band table]

now we can define two measures to count the amounts and product counts in the configuration tables selection

```
Amount Total Band = 
COUNTROWS(
    FILTER(
        ALL( 'Table'[Id] ),
        [Amount Total] > MIN( 'Amount Band'[From] )
            && [Amount Total] <= MAX( 'Amount Band'[To] )
    )
)
```

and

```
Product Count Density Band = 
COUNTROWS(
    FILTER(
        ALL( 'Table'[Id] ),
        [Product Count] >= MIN( 'Product Density Band'[Product Density Band] )
            && [Product Count] <= MAX( 'Product Density Band'[Product Density Band] )
    )
)
```

these measures used in a Table visual with the configuration tables give the desired result

[image: resulting table visuals]

Comment: the sample pbix can be downloaded here : https://github.com/SergioMurru/shared/raw/main/Pratham%20Get%20Count%20of%20Measure%20for%20Aggregate%20Bins%20in%20Power%20BI/Pratham%20Get%20Count%20of%20Measure%20for%20Aggregate%20Bins%20in%20Power%20BI.pbix